# Find whether an element is overlapped by another element with just id of first element

Tags: javascript

what I am trying to do is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Stacked Elements</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="abc" style="height: 200px;width: 300px;position: absolute;">
    <img src="http://d1s9j44aio5gjs.cloudfront.net/2015/11/Duckling_Award_1_Learn_to_Swim.gif" style="height: 200px;width: 300px;">
</div>
<div id="def" style="height: 400px;width: 400px;border:1px solid yellow;position: absolute;">
    <br/>
    <img src="http://media.148apps.com/screenshots/586083949/us-ipad-3-the-ugly-duckling-by-andersen-an-interactive-childrens-story-and-learning-game.jpeg" style="height: 100px;width: 200px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

consider a  page like this where I just know the id of first element which is abc, I want to check whether abc is overlapped by any other element on the page or not and also if it does is it on front or back of that div

to do this I dont want to use the loop , I am seeking for a simple yet effective low cost operation which can give me answer whether the div meets above said conditions or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use parent property of element.
E.g:

```js
var element = $("#abc").parent();
//console.log("Parent Element:",element[0]['nodeName'])
if(element[0]['nodeName']=='BODY'){
  $('.abc').html('ABC element is not overlapped under any element');
}

var element =($("#abc-child").parent());
//console.log("Parent Element:",element)
if(element[0]['nodeName']!='BODY'){
  $('.abc-child').html('ABC-Child element is overlapped under <b>"'+element[0]['id']+'"</b> element');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;background-color:red;float">
   <div id="abc-child" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;background-color:black">     
   </div>
</div>

<p class="abc"></p>
<p class="abc-child"></p>
```

Comment: nice answer......... but I wanted to know whether abc is overlapped by other element or not. can you suggest me with some tips on it

Comment: Our main code start from BODY tag so, we can consider it as parent DOM. If we check that if any DOM has parent BODY then he has not overlapped by any other element

Comment: Please check updated code, where I am showing child div under which div.